# Value initialization of template object using new

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class with a pointer to T

```
template <typename T>
class ScopedPtr
{
    T* ptr_;
public:
    ScopedPtr();
    ~ScopedPtr();
//Copy and move ctors are removed to be short
}

template <typename T>
ScopedPtr<T>::ScopedPtr() :  ptr_(new T{})
{}
```

And I want to use it as follows:

```
struct Numeric_t
{
    int integer_;
    double real_;

    Load_t(int integer = 0, double real = 0) : integer_(integer), real_(real)
    {}
};

struct String_t
{
    std::string str_;

    String_t(std::string str) : str_(str);
    {}
};

int main()
{
    ScopedPtr<Numeric_t> num{1, 2.0};
    ScopedPtr<String_t> str{"Hello, world"};
}
```

Is there some way to define general ScopedPtr ctor to make Numeric_t and String_t value initialized?
Like so:

```
ScopedPtr<T>::ScopedPtr(//some data, depending on type//) :  ptr_(new T{//some data//})
{}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` together with `std::make_unique` (since C++14) already has basically this functionality. (With `auto num = std::make_unique<Numeric_t>(1, 2.0);` syntax.) It doesn't use braced-initialization though if that is important to you.

Comment: You looking for something like this? https://godbolt.org/z/c46Efx9sh  You should read up on the rule of "all or none" for C++.

Comment: @user17732522, Thanks, but I'm doing this for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual perfect forwarding comes to mind:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename... Args>
ScopedPtr<T>::ScopedPtr(Args&&... args) :  ptr_(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...})
{}
```